# Why cloning of a row is raising an org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjException?

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm trying to fetch a Row1 from Table A clone it to create a Row2.
I've used dozer to map/clone the beans.
I've also set the primary key to `null`. It is an auto increment key with `Long` type.

Yet I'm getting the following exception:

> org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is due to a misunderstanding of Hibernate mechanisms.  You shouldn't try to `clone()` Hibernate managed objects, but instead create new ones and then persist them into the database by the means the Hibernate session gives you.

This way your new object will have a properly generated identifier and you shouldn't raise that kind of error again.